# Why did the 10.8.3 update disappear from the App Store after I restarted my new Mac?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I’ve just bought a new Mac with 10.8.2 pre-installed. When I started it up for the first time, once I’d gone through the initial set-up, the App Store launched, and showed me an iPhoto update, and some system updates including Mac OS X 10.8.3.

I quit the App Store, set up another account on the Mac to be my admin account, and edited my main account so that it wasn’t an admin any more. I restarted the Mac, logged in with my main (i.e. non-admin) account, and opened up the App Store again to install the updates.

The iPhoto update showed up, but the systems updates didn’t.

I installed the iPhoto update successfully. I then changed my main account back to being an admin account, thinking that maybe somehow that affected updates. I restarted the Mac, logged in using my main account (now an admin account again), and re-launched the App Store. Still no 10.8.3 or system updates listed.

Any idea what’s going on? On my old Mac, running 10.7, my main account was non-admin, and I didn’t have any problems installing OS X updates.

Comment: You mean the initial configuration was already done? Someone might have chosen to ignore that update.

Comment: @Ryccardo: ah: no, I did the initial configuration myself. (And after that was done, saw the 10.8.3 update in the App Store’s updates tab. I just haven’t seen it since my first restart, and About This Mac says I’m still on 10.8.2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue: Brand new out of the box MacBook Pro 13" 10.8.2 preinstalled. Went through exactly the same process outlined by the OP.

Resolved by:

1. Closing the App Store
2. Restarting App Store
3. I then went to Store > Check For Unfinished Downloads

The 10.8.3 update then reappeared and I was able to redownload and install.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sounds worth a try. I didn’t take those steps when I had the issue, but they might have fixed it like they did for you. Many thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I just launched iTunes, and it told me there was a new version of iTunes available. I clicked on the “Download” button, and it opened up the App Store, which now shows all of the system updates I saw before, including Mac OS X 10.8.3, along with iTunes 11.0.2.

No idea why it forgot about them for a while, or if I would have been able to get them back if there wasn’t an iTunes update due. (I’m sure I would eventually.)

Answer (score -1):

I just unboxed my new iMac 27" i7. Clean setup with no migration, I did sign into iCloud. I ran updates first thing when getting to the desktop. Updates for 10.8.3, iPhoto, Airport Utility, Camera Raw and one other I can't recall. I hit restart and an error appeared stating the packages may have corrupted and to try the install again after restart. 
I did so and now it says No Updates Available.

What a drag

Comment: Very odd. You might want to try starting iTunes to see if that prods Software Update back into line, like it did for me.

Comment: Hmm - this seems like more a related issue than something to be of use here. The OP is looking to get 10.8.3 - and you've clearly downloaded that so it's not clear how problems post-10.8.3 relate to someone wanting to see 10.8.3 in the store in the first place.